# Wordpress 6 script-loader.php issue

Tags: php, wordpress

Dears,
I did reset my WordPress website after updating to wp 6 and now I have this issue I can't access the website

> Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Missing format specifier at end of
> string in /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/script-loader.php:1271
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/script-loader.php(1271):
> sprintf('\xD8\xAA\xD9\x87\xD8\xA7\xD9\x86\xD9\x8A\xD9\x86\xD8\xA7!...',
> 'https://wordpre...', '<button type="b...') #1
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307):
> wp_default_scripts(Object(WP_Scripts)) #2
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331):
> WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #3
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/plugin.php(524):
> WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #4
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php(167):
> do_action_ref_array('wp_default_scri...', Array) #5
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php(142):
> WP_Scripts->init() #6
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php(24):
> WP_Scripts->__construct() #7
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php(147):
> wp_scripts() #8
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-text.php(59):
> wp_add_inline_script('text-widgets', 'wp.textWidgets....') #9
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php(274):
> WP_Widget_Text->_register_one() #10
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php(102):
> WP_Widget->_register() #11
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307):
> WP_Widget_Factory->_register_widgets('') #12
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331):
> WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #13
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/plugin.php(476):
> WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #14
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/widgets.php(1854):
> do_action('widgets_init') #15
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307):
> wp_widgets_init('') #16
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331):
> WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #17
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/plugin.php(476):
> WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #18
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-settings.php(598): do_action('init') #19
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-config.php(112):
> require_once('/home/bahr/bahr...') #20
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-load.php(50):
> require_once('/home/bahr/bahr...') #21
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-blog-header.php(13):
> require_once('/home/bahr/bahr...') #22
> /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/index.php(17): require('/home/bahr/bahr...')
> #23 {main} thrown in /home/bahr/bahrtales.com/wp-includes/script-loader.php on line 1271

What shall I do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All my companies sites went down suddenly i opened the file and removed the secon % from line 1266

```
__( 'Hurray! Your theme supports Full Site Editing with blocks. <a href="%1$s">Tell me more</a>. %2$s' ),
```

it should look like this:

```
__( 'Hurray! Your theme supports Full Site Editing with blocks. <a href="%1$s">Tell me more</a>. 2$s' ),
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: It works, but there's some issues on loading scripts via elementor

Comment: which file are you talking about??

Comment: Thank you, my day is saved after 2 hours of searching around. Any clue what is the reason behind this?